# How can I specify a different URL and/or Browser to run my C# WebDriver test against at runtime?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, runtime, nunit

I am using WebDriver and NUnit to create tests in C#. Is there a way to specify at runtime the URL and the Browser without having to change the code and rebuild?

Basically can I run the same tests against different URLs (Dev, QA , UAT etc) and different Browsers without having to recomplile.

Many Thanks.

Comment: I know I have to use NUnit Configuration files but I am getting problems such as this: 
No test is available in C:\\WebDriver\ConfigFileTest\ConfigFileTest\bin\Debug\ConfigFileTest.dll. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching I eventually came up with the solution by combining the best bits of two other incomplete solutions.

Config file should be the same name as your test file dll eg TestFile.dll.config and located in the same folder.

This is the format of your config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <startup>
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
   </startup>
   <appSettings>
     <add key="TestURL" value="http://www.example.com/"/>
     <add key="Browser" value="Firefox"/>
   </appSettings>
 </configuration>
```

Add a reference and a using statement for System.Configuration and use code like this to access your parameters:

```
 testURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestURL"];
 browser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Browser"];
```

All improvements, suggestions and comments are welcome.

Comment: You don't need to be doing this, NUnit supports parameterised tests for this very reason.

Comment: Please share your knowledge in the form of an answer

Comment: So you manually change config file on all servers with links to different url?